# Can't check if modal is open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can't check if the modal is open or not. Below is my code.

```html
<button id="btnOpenModal" class="btn btn-primary lift" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open Modal 
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade fixed-right" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-vertical d-none" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content bg-glass">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#btnOpenModal").on("click", function(e) {
        if($('#myModal').hasClass("show")) console.log("shown");
    }));
});
```

The modal is dynamically added `show` class into its class when the button is clicked, and I want to check that `show` class is there.

Comment: Could you please add a [Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes. @SamMunroe. When I inspect the modal after the button is clicked, the modal div has `show` class. But I can't get that in my jquery, but I can get `fade` or `fixed-right` which are also classes of the modal as you can see in the above code.

Comment: Can you try like this `$("#btnOpenModal").on("click", function(e) { if($('#myModal').is(":visible")){ console.log("shown") } });` ?

Comment: Not working! I added @Swati's code both inside button onclick event and outside. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the if statement that you wrapped around the modal button onclick event, like so:

```
   $("#btnOpenModal").on("click", function(e) { 
   setTimeout(()=>{
   if($('#myModal').hasClass("show"))     {console.log("shown");}
   }, 2000)
   });
```

It will wait for 2 seconds and then perform the check

Comment: Not working! It doesn't show the `shown` message.

Comment: I've edited my comment, check it now if it works

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. The wired thing is I can get `fade` and `fixed-right` classes but that `show` one.

Comment: I've edited it again, I added setTimeout that will allow it to wait for 2 seconds before performing the check

Comment: Yes. IT WORKS. Thank you very much. But is it the normal way to achieve it?

Comment: Yes, I because it will have to wait for the DOM to add the show class, if not the if statement check will fire before the DOM adds the show class and it will not do anything since the modal does not have the show class, please rate my comment